# Font size extremely small on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, font-size

I have a `<p>` block in a huge `<div>` in the main body of my html with 80% in `font-size`, and also I have a footer `<div>` in the lower part of my body.

The text in the footer has also 80% `font-size`, and if I test it on my PC it is equal, but if I test it in a mobile device, the text of the footer is extremely small, impossible to be read.

How is this possible? Which is the explanation and how can this be avoided?

My main text:

```
<div id="mainTextContainer" class="text">
    <p>test text</p>
</div>
```

My footer:

```
<div id="cookiesBar">
    <div>
        Esta web utiliza 'cookies' para su navegación.
        Al utilizar nuestros servicios aceptas su uso.         
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#cookiesBar {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    background-color: rgba(136, 188, 182, 0.7);
    z-index: 99999;
    border-radius: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 80%;
    font-family: verdana;
}

#mainTextContainer {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.text {
    font-size: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Have you added the ***viewport meta tag*** to your document?

If not, add this to your head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

A mobile browser will naturally attempt to zoom out to display your entire web page like a desktop browser. The viewport meta tag scales your page to the device width.

More information:

- [A tale of two viewports](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html) ~ QuirksMode.org
- [Using the viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag) ~ MDN

Comment: Actually it scales to physical width not 'virtual'. Retina display on iphone 6s plus is full hd but physical size of screen in pixels is about 400.

Comment: @Covik, I wrote "device width" in my answer. Is that not the physical width?

Comment: Yeah you're right. I just made that clear and gave an example so he can understand it better. Cheers!

Comment: I was having problems where the contents of `<pre><code>` blocks was being displayed in a tiny font while everything else looked normal. Adding this line made it go away.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of IOS you're using it may actually be an issue, with that version of the browser.

Just declare the base font size:

```
body {
 ~mybase font size
}
```

Comment: it nos IOS, it is nexus 5 tested with F12 in desktop version chrome

Comment: Please use the same markup as the rest of the document. All text should be in paragraphs.... <div id="cookiesBar">
        <p>
            Esta web utiliza 'cookies' para su navegación. Al utilizar nuestros servicios
            aceptas su uso.        
        </p>
    </div>