# Long pages on Website Creates a Right Margin on Mobile Devices

Tags: php, html, css, mobile, mobile-safari

When I view my website on a mobile device and if a page is longer than the height of the mobile device display, then it will automatically zoom out so that the whole length of the page is displayed on the screen, instead of displaying a scroll bar. This creates a margin at right side. It will do this until the page reaches a certain length, then it will display the scroll bar, but the right margin is still there.

Here is a sample page:
http://theprophecy.tv/testing/product1.php

How can I fix this issue?

My site is not yet mobile friendly. It is showing full site on mobile.

Comment: Provide code for us please.
**EDIT**
What do you have in terms of device scale in your header?

Comment: This answer I posted today may help you: [***don't forget to include the viewport meta tag***](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35564095/3597276)

Comment: @Michael_B Yes, I believe that that is what his problem will be. Some code would be nice though, wouldn't it?

Comment: @KeithAnderson, agreed. Not only nice, but actually required by [**SO guidelines**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), or the question may be closed.

Comment: @Michael_B I don't really want to waste my flags though...

Comment: @Michael_B tried including the viewport meta tag but it did not fix the problem

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question and, if possible, a demo that reproduces the problem. One demo tool is jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I tested your website, and had no problems.

Comment: @KeithAnderson I fixed the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! There was a div in the header with a width that was extending past the header container.