# Bottom part of screen covered up by navigation bar

Tags: css, mobile, backbone.js, screen, navbar

I am building a mobile app and encountered an issue where the bottom part of my screen is covered up by the bottom navigation screen.

Screenshot of issue
[image]

I tried to add a margin bottom as below:

```
  .dashboard(style="margin-bottom: 58px; margin-top: -10px;")
    #region
    #menu-region
```

The strange thing is that this works if I run the code on my desktop but does not work when it is run on the mobile phone.

Question: How can I update the CSS so that it allows me to add a padding at the bottom of the screen so that the bottom part of the screen is not covered by the nav bar on the mobile?

## CSS for bottombar

```
.bottombar {
  background-color: $theme-color;
  height: 58px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 1000;

  .footer-icon {
    padding-top: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20%;
  }

  table {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;

    tr {
      td {
        width:20%;
        background-color: transparent;
        text-align: center;
        position: relative;
      }
      .menu-corner-color {
        background-color: #1189b6;
      }
      .menu-side-color {
        background-color: #006990;
      }
      .menu-middle-color {
        background-color: #004965;
      }
      .circle {

      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Jade for layout

```
.footermenu
  .bottombar
    table(style="width:100%; height: 100%; border: 0px; padding: 0px; border-spacing: 0px; background-color: ")
      tr
        td.notifications.menu-corner-color
          i.material-icons.md-light.md-24 &#xE7F4;
          span.badge_count.hide
        td.coach_chat.menu-side-color
          i.material-icons.md-light.md-24 &#xE0BF;
          span.badge_count.hide
        td.log.menu-middle-color
          i.material-icons.md-light.md-24 &#xE145;
        td.community.menu-side-color
          i.material-icons.md-light.md-24 &#xE7FB;
          span.badge_count.hide
        td.profile.menu-corner-color
          i.material-icons.md-light.md-24 &#xE7FD;
```

Comment: The content just doesn't fit on the screen. I'm guessing your computer screen has a larger height than your mobile device. What's the CSS for the navbar?

Comment: Have you added the *viewport meta tag* to your document? http://stackoverflow.com/a/35564095/3597276

Comment: @J.Titus, on the desktop, I shrinked the screen to mimic the mobile screen. The starting state is the same as what is seen in the screenshot, just that I was able to scroll down and see the rest of the screen. Whereas if I load the app on a actual mobile screen, the margin-bottom of 58px seemed to have been gone. I have updated the OP to include the CSS and code for navbar (footermenu)

Comment: have you tired adding the bottom margin to the body and not the dashboard?

Comment: @Zhen Sorry, I wasn't completely clear. Pixel density also affects how a layout is portrayed in a browser on a desktop vs on a mobile device. The viewport meta tag mentioned by Michael is required. Also, you should be using Chrome's mobile device screen emulation tool, because it will more accurately depict the layout than just a shrunken browser window.

Comment: Can you provide the generated `html` or a [mcve]...?