# How to use Swift WKWebView to load html page content in large size

Tags: html, ios, swift, wkwebview

I am new to the `WKWebView` which I am using to load a privacy policy from an url in my application. The html is loading perfect but the content size is too small, I find it difficult to read on small screen size devices like 5s or iPhone SE.
Here [image: image of wkwebview]

Is there any way to enlarge this contents?
Please let me know the best approach to solve this problem.
Thank You.

Comment: this is usually fixed on the server check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35564095/6689101)

Comment: Thank you @zombie

Comment: @user9496018 Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509128/10150796

Answer (score 0):

Use some CSS inside the privacy file (privacy.html).

```
<head>
    <style>
       html {
            height:100%;
       }
       body {
            font-family: "SourceSansPro-Semibold", Arial, serif; //your font
            font-size:large; //change this size to what fits
            background-color:#FFF;
            color: #000;
            margin:0;
            height:100%;
            padding:20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```